# FFMpeg incorrect execution calling two different paths in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to take screenshots from a movie file and my app crashes with the following error:

```
 $ FFMPEG_PATH=C:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ node .
 =====Convert Video Failed======
{ [Error: spawn c:\Apps\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\ffprobe.exe ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe\r\nc:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\\ffprobe.exe',
  path: 'c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe\r\nc:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\\ffprobe.exe',
  spawnargs:
   [ '-show_streams',
     '-show_format',
     'j:\\some.avi' ] }
stdout: undefined
stderr: undefined
```

As you can see I'm passing a the `FFMPEG_PATH` env variable because otherwise I'm getting a similar error:

```
$ node .
 =====Convert Video Failed======
{ [Error: spawn c:\Apps\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\ffprobe.exe ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe\r\nc:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\\ffprobe.exe',
  path: 'c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe\r\nc:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\\ffprobe.exe',
  spawnargs:
   [ '-show_streams',
     '-show_format',
     'j:\\some.avi' ] }
stdout: undefined
stderr: undefined
```

In both cases you can see that the command that node/fluent-ffmpeg is using results in a double path like this: `c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe\r\nc:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\\ffprobe.exe` which obviously fails.

What causes this and how do I fix it?

---

Win 7, Node `v4.1.2`, ffmpeg version `N-76041-g0418541`

The code I'm using:

```js
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
// ffmpeg.setFfprobePath("c:\\Apps\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");

var filename = 'j:\\some.avi';
var command = ffmpeg(filename);


// Code from an example
command
  .on('filenames', function(filenames) {
    console.log('Will generate ' + filenames.join(', '))
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Screenshots taken');
  })
  .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(" =====Convert Video Failed======");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("stdout: " + stdout);
    console.log("stderr: " + stderr);
  })
  .screenshots({
    // Will take screens at 20%, 40%, 60% and 80% of the video
    count: 4,
    folder: 'd:\\projects\\pics'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It only happens in Git Bash - which I got used to working in window with. Running the script in normal cmd works properly.